# Unexpected storage path while running hdfs namenode -format

Tags: macos, hadoop, storage

I'm trying to set up hadoop on my Mac Mojave 10.14.6. The hadoop version I'm using is 3.0.3

I followed this tutorial to set up the config: https://dbmstutorials.com/hive/hdfs-setup-on-mac.html

While running `hdfs namenode -format` they ask me:

Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory /Users/xavier/$HOME/hadoop/hadoop_storage ? (Y or N)

Problem is that this path doesn't exist and it does create a $HOME file in the /Users/xavier

My .bash_profile config is as follow:

```
## Set Java Home as env variable
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home

## Set HADOOP environment variables
export HADOOP_HOME=$HOME/hadoop/hadoop-3.0.3
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/libexec
export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native:$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_PREFIX=$HOME/hadoop

# Set Path to the Hadoop Binary
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

Does anyone have a clue of why this could happen ?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the namenode and datanode storage locations in hdfs-site.xml

These aren't to be used literally, but actually replaced with a real folder (which will be created if it doesn't exist). `$HOME` doesn't mean anything to the xml, only in the shell

```
<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>[$HOME Path]/hadoop/hadoop_storage</value>
<final>true</final>
</property>
```